# Using nest and map in combination with mgcv gam and broom augment

Tags: r, spline, gam, mgcv, broom

I am trying to create a smooth spline for each sample in a grouped dataframe. For this I am using a nest and map approach and mgcv gam (following this example https://smu095.github.io/2019/02/16/2019-02-16-tidytuesday-fitting-multiple-time-series-models-using-purrr/).

After running the gam I would like to use broom::augment to extract the fitted data and calculate confidence intervals.

This code works using broom 0.5.6 but throws an error using the new broom 0.7 version. broom::tidy and broom:glance still work with this format but augment stops with "Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `augment_spline`.
x object 'year' not found"

Example code below

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)

#Use the gapminder dataset that comes with dslabs as an example
glimpse(gapminder)

gapminder_nest <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  nest()%>%
  mutate(splined =map(data, ~mgcv::gam(population ~ s(year, k=5, bs="tp"), data=.x))) %>%
  mutate(augment_spline= map(splined, broom::augment))%>%
  unnest(augment_spline)%>%
  dplyr::select(country, population,.fitted,.se.fit)
```

Same code runs if using broom 0.5.6

```
devtools::install_version("broom", version = "0.5.6", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

All online tutorials I could find present similar code that doesn't seem to work using broom 0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newer version I think it also needs data in `newdata` argument. You can pass the data as separate argument with `map2`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)

gapminder_nest <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  nest()%>%
  mutate(splined = map(data, ~mgcv::gam(population ~ s(year, k=5, bs="tp"), data=.x))) %>%
  mutate(augment_spline = map2(splined, data, ~broom::augment(.x, newdata = .y))) %>%
  unnest(augment_spline)
```

Although this works but this doesn't return all the columns as the 0.5.6 version of `broom` does i.e `se.fit`,`.resid`,`.hat`, `.sigma` and `.cooksd`.This only returns `.fitted` column.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly and now I will learn about map2. Adding se_fit = TRUE to the augment call also returned the .se.fit column